# Is it true that constructor returns an object?

Tags: java, constructor

```
class Test{
  public Test(){
    System.out.println("I am here");
    return;// not getting error
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    Test test = new Test();
  }
}
```

I am java beginner. My tutor told me that constructor returns an object and showed me the above example. is it really happening because method is not returning any value but the `return;`is not getting an error.

Comment: No the constructor does not return an object. The `new` keyword causes the JVM to create the object, call its constructor, and then "return" the object.

Comment: *[INFO]* `return` keyword simply returns the flow to method signature (basically skipping the code after return statement). Try writing some `print` statement after return. And this signature of `return` is used in `void` method **not in method with return type** :P

Comment: got it, but constructor does not have `return` type even `void` and compiler not getting error here, so i was confused.

Comment: @I_Am_Innocent 'To method signature'? What are you talking about?

Comment: @EJP sorry for weak communication skills, actually all I meant was the the `rest of the code won't be executed`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, a constructor initialises an object that's already been created.  It doesn't return an object.  Your tutor is wrong.

You don't need to write `return;` inside a constructor, unless you're returning before the end of the code.

Answer (score 2):

No. The role of constructor is to initialize the state of the object.

`new` keyword is responsible to create an object in the heap. In below example, using `new` keyword you are creating an object and then you are pointing that object with type `Test` variable name `test`.

```
 Test test = new Test();
```

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not true at all

A constructor in Java is a block of code similar to a method that’s called when an instance of an object is created. Here are the key differences between a constructor and a method:

- A constructor doesn’t have a return type.
- The name of the constructor must be the same as the name of the class.
- Unlike methods, constructors are not considered members of a class.
- A constructor is called automatically when a new instance of an
  object is created.

**Example:**

```
class Bike1{  
    Bike1(){
        System.out.println("Bike is created");
    }  

    public static void main(String args[]){  
        Bike1 b=new Bike1();  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this line of code

```
return;
```

dose not mean return value but it just end the execution of contractor and since it's in the last line so it's not necessarily

situation where you use `return` in constructor

```
class Test
{

  private int a;
  public Test(int a)
  {
    System.out.println("I am here");
    if(a>10)
    {
        System.out.println("I'm Executed but not the rest of code");
        return;
    }
    System.out.println("I'm the last line of constructor"); 
  }

  ...

}
```

`return` in `constructor` its just like `return` in `void` method

Answer (score 1):

Constructor in java is a special type of method that is used to initialize the object.

Java constructor is invoked at the time of object creation. It constructs the values i.e. provides data for the object that is why it is known as the constructor.

But it doesn't have a return type, I'm afraid your tutor is wrong about this, please rediscuss it with him.

```
class Car{  
Car()
{
System.out.println("Car is created");
}  
    public static void main(String args[])
{  
    Car c=new Car();  
    } 
 }
```

Comment: Hello, I understand you are new here but please check the formatting before posting your answer.